# Spring @Scheduled with fixed rate running multiple times

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I'm using a @Scheduled with fixed rate spring annotaion in my service.
In the iteration im doing some logic and send http request.
I'm running it every 2 seconds and most of the time it is okay.
I have a log to console that tells me that a new iteration beigns.
Sometimes, the log is presented 4/6 times per second.
I also have a log that tells me how long the iteration took, and it never exceeded more than 1 second.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class Handler {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void handle() {
        System.out.println("Start iteration");
        // -- logic --
    }
}
```

I'm using sprintboot version 2.1.2.RELEASE.
Any ideas?

running every 2 seconds

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: All `@Scheduled` methods share the same executor. If you have other functions which are keeping that executor busy, you may see behaviour like you described. Stop-the-world GC events will have an impact too. Both `fixedRate` and `fixedDelay` are made on a best-effort basis. There is no guarantee.